# How to change the download folder in Google Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-api

When downloading a file, I specify the file name like this:

```
chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename.addListener
```

But you need to change the file save folder. Actually the question is: how can this be done? What method to use?
The only thing I've come up with is to cancel the download and start a new one in the right folder.

Comment: It can be a relative path inside the default downloads folder. You can't change the base folder. Otherwise it'd be an extremely huge security hole.

Comment: @wOxxOm, but how do I change the download folder? I dont know method or prop.

Comment: Only the user can change it.

Comment: @wOxxOm, no. For example: extension FireShot load files to your directory. And I understood how to load in diretory, but I see infinite loop. Show code?

Comment: As you can easily see in that extension's manifest and source code it uses nativeMessaging and a companion native OS utility, installed separately, that has full access to the user's file system.

Comment: @wOxxOm, okay. I think I did what I wanted. but I need to somehow correctly stop the execution of the script, since it is executed infinitely.U cansee my code? https://gist.github.com/kolik29/fb009e9a267bbbfd3e5128c92432c3d7

Comment: You're reloading your extension page which is probably not what you want. If you want to reload the web page, either inject `location.reload()` using chrome.tabs.executeScript or use chrome.tabs.reload.

Comment: @wOxxOm, no. I want to stop the endless download. I subscribe to the download event, inside of which the download stops and a new folder starts in the folder I need. this happens indefinitely or until I reload the page. Whether it is possible as that otpisitsja from event.